# Convert pandas dataframe to 2 deep dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a Pandas dataframe with some data, and I want to convert this data in a two deep dictionary.

```
Subject_id    Exam1    Exam2    
Subject_1         9        5                 
Subject_2         7        4                 
Subject_3         3        8
```

Now what I want is a dictionary structures like this

```
{'Subject_1': {'Exam1': 9, 
               'Exam2': 5}
 'Subject_2': {'Exam1': 7, 
               'Exam2': 4}
 'Subject_3': {'Exam1': 3, 
               'Exam2': 8}
}
```

I tried basically using two loops, one for each row to iterate over all the subjects and then one for each column. And then I build the dict something like this.

```
for i in df.size[0]:
    for j in df.size[1]:
        # df[i][j] has the score of subject_i and exam_j
        my_dict[df[i]] = df[i][j]
```

However my Dataframe is big, and I would like a more elegant way of achieving this (something like creating the dictionary with `zip` but since it's a two deep dict and some info is columnwise (subjects) and other info rowwise (exam notes for particular subject) I could not manage to do it.

How could I get the desired dict from my input dataframe in a pythonic and elegant way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.to_dict('index')`

```
In [53]: df.set_index('Subject_id').to_dict('index')
Out[53]:
{'Subject_1': {'Exam1': 9L, 'Exam2': 5L},
 'Subject_2': {'Exam1': 7L, 'Exam2': 4L},
 'Subject_3': {'Exam1': 3L, 'Exam2': 8L}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more simply, just `df.to_dict(orient="index")` should do it.